# SQL query select from all tables where ID equals

Tags: mysql, sql

Relatively straight forward question but I am a novice with SQL queries. I'm trying to find in all the tables any record that contains a certain value.

So in a nutshell I want to find in the entire database any instance where the hContactId is 200.

I've tried the following:

```
USE dbname
SELECT *
FROM sys.Tables
WHERE hContacts.hContactId = 200;
```

I end up with

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version

I've seen some really complex queries like below that didn't work but surely there should be a way to query all tables for an integer right?

Another thing I tried to the same error message:

```
declare  @sql varchar(8000), @tbl varchar(255), @col varchar(255), 
@data  varchar(50)

set @data = '200'

declare cur_tbl cursor for
     select a.name, b.name from sysobjects a, syscolumns b, systypes c where a.id = b.id and a.type = 'U' and c.xtype = b.xtype and c.name in ( 'int' )
open cur_tbl
fetch next from cur_tbl into @tbl, @col
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
     set @sql = '
                   if exists (select * from [' + @tbl + '] where convert( varchar(255), [' + @col + '] ) = ''' + @data + ''')
                         select tbl=''' + @tbl + ''', col=''' + @col + ''', [' + @col + '], * from [' + @tbl + '] where convert( varchar(255), [' + @col + '] ) = ''' + @data + '''
                   '
     exec(@sql)

     fetch next from cur_tbl into @tbl, @col
end
close cur_tbl
deallocate cur_tbl
```

Again just looking for a basic query on all tables looking for those that match the hContactId. Any ideas?

Comment: ...for the right syntax to use near...

Comment: You need to iterate over all the tables.  I would suggest using MariaDB/MySQL syntax and system tables rather than MS SQL syntax and system tables.

Comment: You first have to find all tables that have a column named `hContactID` by querying your RDBMS's system tables. Then you have to craft a SQL statement that selects from that table `WHERE hContactID = 2000`. Then you have to execute that sql statement and see if it returns rows or not. This isn't a simple exercise since dynamically generated sql is required since you don't know which tables to query (which tables have a column named `hContactID`)

Comment: This looks to be about MariaDB rather than MySQL, which can (depending on the version) make a difference in how you can accomplish certain results

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always use a union:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_name_1
WHERE hContactId = 200;
UNION  
SELECT * FROM Table_name_2 
WHERE hContactId = 200;
UNION  
SELECT * FROM Table_name_3 
WHERE hContactId = 200;
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way would be to search all in SQL using the * (everything call) from each table using the UNION key word. this method will allow for as many tables as you are currently working with to be searched for the required data.

EXAMPLE:

SELECT *
FROM TABLE 1
WHERE hContacts.hContactId = 200;
UNION
SELECT *
FROM TABLE 2
WHERE hContacts.hContactId = 200;
UNION
SELECT *
FROM TABLE 3
WHERE hContacts.hContactId = 200;
etc.....